# XCode 12: iPhone XR: CDVWKWebViewUIDelegate.m:124:40: Too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 2

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, xcode12

Trying to build the mobile app and launch it to my iPhone XR. Can't seem to figure out why its working on iOS Simulator but Cordova issue when trying to build on iPhone XR. Have tried looking for a solution for this for sometime, if someone can help would be much appreciated !

Please see screenshot below for the exact error and line.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to avoid the error, try adding an explicit type cast:

```
((id (*)(id, SEL))imp)(self, sel);
```

Comment: I will give it a try, meanwhile it would be nice to understand the reasoning and implications of this issue